# adding filter in certain ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Having some HTML

```
 <div ng-class="{mi_selected: value.selected}" ng-repeat="value in param.values" >
            {{value.type == "text" || value.type == "relocate_here" || value.type =="relocatePage" || value.type=="reloadDashboard" ? value.name : ""}}
 </div>
```

But I have one more `value.type='currency'`.And if it is so I need add filter`| currency:'RUB '`. 
How can I do that, if this construction

```
 {{value.type == "text" || value.type == "relocate_here" || value.type =="relocatePage" || value.type=="reloadDashboard" ? value.name : value.type=="currency" ? value.name | currency: 'EUR' :""}}
```

doesn't work.
HTML exactly looks like:

```
<div ng-class="{mi_selected: value.selected}" ng-repeat="value in param.values" ng-click="value.type=='relocate_here' ? dashboardCtrl.relocateHere(value.urlTo) : value.type=='relocatePage' ? dashboardCtrl.relocatePage(value.urlTo) : value.type=='reloadDashboard' ? dashboardCtrl.reloadDashboard(value.json,value.matrix) : ''">
            {{value.type == "text" || value.type == "relocate_here" || value.type =="relocatePage" || value.type=="reloadDashboard" ? value.name : ""}}

            <input ng-if="value.type == 'input'" type="text" ng-value="value.selected" placeholder="{{value.name}}">
            <input ng-if="value.type == 'input_search'" name="value.model" ng-model="value.val" ng-controller="searchCtrl as searchCtrl" ng-change="searchCtrl.isEmptyQuery(param.values) ? searchCtrl.isEmptyObject(searchCtrl.template) ? searchCtrl.search(param.values, param.url) : searchCtrl.checkTemplate(param.values) ? searchCtrl.searchFilter(param.values) : searchCtrl.search(param.values, param.url) : searchCtrl.clean()" type="text" placeholder="{{value.name}}">
            <input ng-if="value.type == 'date_search'" type="date">
        </div>
```

For example have `value.name=1000`.If `value.type=="text"` I need to display `1000`. But if `value.type=="currency"`, I need to display `EUR 1,000.00`

Comment: you should read how the ternary operator works.

Comment: @PhilippSander I understand that problem in `:`...

Comment: yes, because you use it really weird...

Comment: @PhilippSander your comments doesn't help

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: read this.... if you're being rude, nobody will help you

Comment: @PhilippSander I am sorry  if I seemed to be rude, I did not mean to be rude

Comment: please provide us some input and expected output

Comment: @PhilippSander I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling controller function you can try this

```
<div ng-class="{mi_selected: value.selected}" ng-repeat="value in param.values" >{{ showValue(value.type) }}
 </div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.showValue = function(type){
  if(type=="currency"){ return $filter('currency')(type, 'RUB '); } return type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using a custom filter like this:

```js
var filterByType = function($filter) {
  return function(data, type) {
    if (type === 'text') {
      return data;
    }
    if (type === 'currency') {
      //change the data path to name
      return $filter('currency')(data.amount, 'RUB');
    }
  }
};
```

```html
{{ value | filterByType : value.type}}
```

Answer (score -1):

inside you ng-repeat, you can have a condition with and ng-if.
you will just need to test if `ng-if == 'currency'` and in this case display the line with the filter, if not display the line without the filter

Comment: So as I understand to do like you said I need to add element inside my div with `ng-if` directive, but I need to do this without adding new element